# How to estimate the source of variation in R? (For two-way ANOVA)

Tags: r, anova, summary

In my laboratory we used a statistical software package, but now we are using R for the statistics.

Using the statistical software, after a two-way ANOVA, a table with the results includes "Source of variation" and "% of total variation". How can I get those values from R?

**Example:**
This data set

```
Temperature <- factor(c(rep("cold", times = 4),
                        rep("hot", times = 4)),
                      levels = c("cold", "hot"))

Light <- factor(rep(c(rep("blue", times = 2),
                      rep("yellow", times = 2)),
                    times = 2),
                levels = c("blue", "yellow"))

Result <- c(90.40, 85.20, 21.70, 25.30,
            75.12, 77.36, 6.11, 10.8)

Data <- data.frame(Temperature, Light, Result)
```

[image]

2-way ANOVA in R:

```
two_wayANOVA <- aov(data = Data,
                    formula = Result ~ Temperature * Light)
summary(two_wayANOVA)


 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value  Pr(>F)    
Temperature        1    354     354   42.250 0.00289 ** 
Light              1   8723    8723 1041.366 5.5e-06 ***
Temperature:Light  1      6       6    0.725 0.44250    
Residuals          4     34       8                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In the statistical software:

[image]

Comment: You can manually calculate by dividing individual `Sum Sq` values by the sum of `Sum Sq` value. Ex. In case of `Light`, 8723/(354+8723+6+34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @yh6 commented, one can determine the source of variation by dividing the SumSq by the total sum of "Sum Sq".

The broom package has the convenient `tidy` function to take the output from the `aov` function and make it into a data frame for easy handling.

```
library(broom)
output <- tidy(two_wayANOVA)

output$variationSource <- output$sumsq/sum(output$sumsq)*100
output


# A tibble: 4 x 7
  term                 df   sumsq  meansq statistic     p.value variationSource
  <chr>             <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Temperature           1  354.    354.      42.2    0.00289              3.88  
2 Light                 1 8723.   8723.    1041.     0.00000550          95.7   
3 Temperature:Light     1    6.07    6.07     0.725  0.442                0.0666
4 Residuals             4   33.5     8.38    NA      NA                   0.368
```

**Update**
To recreate the significance column, this add this line to the script:

```
output$sig <- cut(output$p.value, breaks=c(0,  0.001,  0.01,  0.05,  0.1, 1), 
                                  labels=c( '***',  '**' , '*' , '.', ' ' ))
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm not an R or statistics expert, so a I need a simple hint from you: How can I create a .doc, or .txt, or. pdf file with this table? I tried using sink("path") , then with(two_wayANOVA), then sink() but didn't work

Comment: The very simple way to export this data is to save it as .csv file and then open it with a spreadsheet, or text processing program.  To save it: `write.csv(output, "myfile.csv" )`

Comment: Hi, me again. There is a way to see in the table that you teach me to put the "*" of the significance?